# Rsyslog running on RHEL unable to forward messages - rsyslogd: action 'action 8' suspended

Tags: redhat, rsyslog, rhel7

I'm trying to configure an rsyslog agent which will forward the log messages to a centralized server. However, I get the following error. The link provided in the error message does not specify the root cause of the error.

```
rsyslogd: action 'action 8' suspended, next retry is Wed Jan 16 2:52:17 2019 [v8.24.0-34.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

Comment: What version of syslog you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improving on Raj's answer above:

Instead of disabling enforcing mode, you should instead configure SELinux to open the connection between the rsyslog daemon and the port listening for messages.

You can do this with a command like:

```
sudo semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p tcp <port>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your rsyslog configuration specifies to log to a file or device that does not exist and cannot be created. Did you make a typo when you edited your configuration?

You can find out which path is being referred to with a command like:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rsyslogd -dn 2>/dev/null | grep "ACTION 8"
```

Answer (score -1):

Upon further troubleshooting, I found that selinux was enabled in **enforcing mode** which led to block rsyslog to send logs. 
Changed selinux mode to permissive, reboot the server and it started working.

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't even have to reboot the server.

Comment: Please change accepted answer to the one by @LukeB. above.  DIsabling selinux or setting it to permissive is a troubleshooting step.  It bypasses the root cause and significantly decreases the security of the system.  Configuring selinux to allow the connection is an actual solution.

Comment: Done. Thanks @Jeter-work